# Gatsby Develop and Build give different results

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

When I am importing code from a js file and displaying it as `<div>{String(code)}</div>` on a webpage where `code` is imported as `import code from "./code.js`.

The problem is `gatsby develop` showing the code on the page as I wrote code in `code.js` but `gatsby build` then `gatsby serve` showing weird code written in one line not exactly same as written in `code.js`.

I don't know why is this happening? Any suggestions?

Comment: is it working properly? after shape change

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That happens because `gatsby build`, by default, uses `uglify` to compress your code in order to make it slimmer for a production environment.

Try running `gatsby build --no-uglify`

Comment: Great! Thanks! That worked. Code is rendered correctly but it's, still, coming in one line.

Comment: Sure, as you are displaying it as a string it serializes it in one line...

Comment: Ok! Is there some way around I can do to display it like a multi line code instead of one line wrapped code?